# Mysql update previous value by adding o subtracting value with limits

Tags: mysql, sql

I've this query

```
UPDATE posts_flags
    INNER JOIN
    users ON (posts_flags.user_id = users.id )
SET 
    users.credibility = users.credibility + 100 /* or -100 */
WHERE posts_flags.content_id = ?;
```

Is it possible to limit the new value in a range, for example 0 - 1000 ?

Comment: Add to WHERE `AND users.credibility < 990`

Comment: simple and brilliant

Comment: Or rather `AND users.credibility < 900` missed you were adding 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend `LEAST()` or `GREATEST()`.  For `+ 100`:

```
UPDATE posts_flags pf INNER JOIN
       users u
       ON pf.user_id = u.id
    SET u.credibility = LEAST(u.credibility + 100, 1000)
WHERE pf.content_id = ?;
```

For `- 100`:

```
UPDATE posts_flags pf INNER JOIN
       users u
       ON pf.user_id = u.id 
    SET u.credibility = GREATEST(u.credibility - 100, 0)
WHERE pf.content_id = ?;
```

If you want to generate an error if the row is outside the range, then in most databases, you can use a `check` constraint (in MySQL you probably need a trigger).  However, you seem to want to impose outer limits, rather than generating an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `CHECK` constraint to generally avoid any inserts/updates outside your allowed range.

```
CREATE TABLE post_flags
(
  credibility INT CHECK (credibility >= 0 AND credibility <= 1000),
);
```

Use `MAX` to give the value a lower bound, `MIN` if you want to give it an upper bound at inserting/updating.

```
UPDATE posts_flags
    INNER JOIN
    users ON (posts_flags.user_id = users.id )
SET 
    users.credibility = MAX(MIN(users.credibility + 100, 1000), 0)
WHERE posts_flags.content_id = ?;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_min.asp

Comment: great solution!

Answer (score 0):

A simple if Clause will do it

```
 users.credibility = if ( (users.credibility + 100) > 1000, 1000
                         ,if((users.credibility + 100)<0, 0,users.credibility + 100))
```